# Parse deploy command error x509

Tags: parse-platform, go

On `parse deploy` command I get this error, how can I solve it?

> x509: failed to load system roots and no roots provided.
>   /home/travis/gopath/src/github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-cli/main.go:143      checkIfSupported
>   /home/travis/gopath/src/github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-cli/main.go:101      main
>   /home/travis/.gimme/versions/go1.4.2.linux.amd64/src/runtime/proc.go:72     main
>   /home/travis/.gimme/versions/go1.4.2.linux.amd64/src/runtime/asm_386.s:2288 goexit

**(OS Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64)**

**UPDATE**
Now sometimes, one in ten attempts, it requests email and password. But, after input password, I get:

> panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference [signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x1 pc=0x8097025]

Comment: Seems parse is trying to send a https request that's failing. Did you change anything in your `/etc/ssl` folder? It's usually required by net/http to access the system roots

Comment: not changed /etc/ssl

Comment: Now I get this, after requesting password:
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x1 pc=0x8097025]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved executing an update-ca-certificates command. I think that certificates were broken and it stopped to work, but I dont know why.